# 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' with LabVIEW database query

Tags: database, labview

I have two tables:

table 1 : info1 -> where i have pid(primary key),name,address,sex etc.

table 2 : visit -> where i have the pid(foreign key), 
                  visit_date,next_visit,details

I used a query

```
SELECT info1.Patient_ID, visit.Visit_Date, visit.Next_Visit, 
visit.Visit_Details from info1, visit WHERE info1.Patient_ID ="%"
```

Is this query correct??

LabVIEW code:
[image: LabVIEW code image]

Front panel:
[image: front panel]

Table 1 (info1):
[image: table contents screenshot]

Table 2 (visit):
[image: table contents screenshot]

Error:
[image: error cluster screenshot]

Comment: Your query needs a JOIN. But first, can you successfully retrieve data from one table at a time?

Comment: yes I tried retrieving data from single table and it works. What kind of join should I use?

Comment: Thank you nekomatic, I got the error. The issue in my was query was of the inverted commas I was using for number input. We only use it when we give string as a input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT info1.Patient_ID, visit.Visit_Date, visit.Next_Visit, visit.Visit_Details 
FROM info1 INNER JOIN visit ON info1.Patient_ID = visit.Patient_ID
WHERE info1.Patient_ID ="%"
```

If you use an `INNER JOIN` as shown above, then you'll only get a result for Patient_ID's that have an entry in **both** of the two tables. If you wanted to see all Patient_ID's whether or not they had a `visit` record, for example, you would use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

**Note:** in the LabVIEW code you've shown, you are constructing the query by building a string from user-supplied data (the `Patient ID` front panel control). This is a really bad idea because it enables *SQL injection attacks* by malicious users. You should look up how to supply the value as a *parameter* to your LabVIEW database functions instead.

Comment: I will take your note into consideration..thank you for the suggestion.